# Centos: TERM environment Variable Not Set

Tags: php, bash, shell, video, ffmpeg

I am working on a mobile application which allows users to upload videos, upon upload the videos are converted to mp4 format, I am using a shell script for that purpose, the script was working fine on our last server but we switched our server and now it has stopped working, the log files of apache are printing.

```
[Tue Jan 21 00:57:37.003944 2014] [:error] TERM environment variable not set.
[Tue Jan 21 00:57:37.148531 2014] [:error] ./script.sh: line 3: ffmpeg: command not found
[Tue Jan 21 00:57:37.148794 2014] [:error] script.sh: line 4: ffmpeg: command not found
```

The content of script.sh are

```
#!/bin/bash -p
clear
ffmpeg -i $filename -strict experimental -ar 22050 converted.mp4<br>
ffmpeg -itsoffset -1 -i  converted.mp4 -vframes 25 -filter:v scale="min(500\, iw):-1"  thumbnail.png
```

I am calling the script form php using

```
shell_exec("script.sh 52567afa374c61381399290.mp4");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Couple of things. Why are you doing `clear` (guessing `TERM` error comes from here) and what do you get if you actually login on the server and run `type ffmpeg` (guessing it might not exist or not found in whatever path it's using)? Also, is "$filename" set to anything?

Comment: ffmpeg is installed and properly configured, when I run the same commands from SSH the commands execute successfully, the clear is just to clear the console before execution, I will try removing that and run again.

Comment: Probably won't change anything if only the TERM error is related to clear. Also try it using the full path to `ffmpeg`, using `shell_exec("bash script.sh 52567afa374c61381399290.mp4");` and I think you need to switch `$filename` to `"$1"` (though I would be somewhat weary of injection here)

Comment: Thanks BrowSlow, Using full path to ffmpeg did it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errors were

- `clear` needs a terminal to process so causes a `TERM` error (bash -p
  should generally fix it, but `clear` isn't really need here anyway)
- The path isn't correctly set during `shell_exec` so `ffmpeg` needed
  to have a full path specified so bash could find it.